# Hitting the rate limit when flagging comments breaks the flag dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, rate-limiting, comment-flags

If you try and flag two comments in a row, you run into the vote rate-limiter:

[image: You may only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds.]

However, after 5 seconds the flag button no longer works; instead you get:

[image: Please specify why you are flagging this comment]

and another 5 second countdown. You need to refresh the page before you can get the flag dialog to come up for that comment

Comment: +1. It'd be super nice if the comment vote interval was per-user based on flag weight: when I take the time to read a pile of comments and decide which ones are over-the-line, I'd love to turn that into a decision in five seconds total, not a minute or two while I wait for a five-second timer to expire over and over again. (And I'm not even getting good at judging five seconds: most of the time it takes me about three clicks before I reach the five seconds.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this - a fix will be pushed tonight.