# Cannot flag additional comments if violate 5 second timer rule

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hitting the rate limit when flagging comments breaks the flag dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94671/hitting-the-rate-limit-when-flagging-comments-breaks-the-flag-dialog)

After flagging a comment and attempting to flag another under 5 seconds, you get the notification that you have to wait at least 5 seconds. After waiting 5 seconds, it says "Please confirm flagging reason" or something to that effect. There is no box to select the flagging reason on your third attempt at hitting the button. You have to refresh the page to continue flagging additional comments.

Comment: Your title says "comments", the first line of your question says "question", and the last line of your question says "comments" again. Which ones are giving you trouble?

Comment: @sarnold: comments.

Answer (score 3):

While this *might* be a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), it seems likely that this is, in fact, [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), since it would probably prevent a flurry of (possibly accidental) flags. And, with the best will in the world, given the (intended) use-case for flags I'd prefer it to be relatively difficult to flag.

Comment: No, it's definitely a bug.